# Effective way to set the Controls enable/disable/hidden on UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

I am working on UI where i have some controls like textbox, button, radiobutton and more.

On some specific business workflows i have to play with my controls and set their state as enable/disable or set visibility of them.

When i do this my whole UI code behind (xaml.cs) scattered with controls enabling and disabling.

i want to write a single method which is completely responsible for handling the state of my UI controls.

Currently what i have done is - making a single function which take the operation as parameter and then based on operation i am playing with my controls.

For example:

```
private const string ADD_OPERATION = "Add";

private const string MODIFY_OPERATION = "Modify";

private const string DELETE_OPERATION = "Delete";

-------------------------------------------------------

/// <summary>
/// Method for disabling controls present on current screen
/// based on various operations like add, delete, edit identity
/// </summary>
private void EnableOrDisableIdentityControl(string operation)
{
    switch (operation)
    {
        case ADD_OPERATION:
            this.EditIdentificationGroupBox.IsEnabled = true;
            this.AddUpdateIdentificationButton.IsEnabled = true;
            this.RelatedEntitiesGridFooter.IsAddButtonEnabled = false;
            this.RelatedEntitiesGridFooter.IsEditButtonEnabled = false;
            this.RelatedEntitiesGridFooter.IsDeleteButtonEnabled = false;
            this.IdentificationDataGrid.IsEnabled = false;

            break;

        case MODIFY_OPERATION:
            this.EditIdentificationGroupBox.IsEnabled = true;

            // Disable identity grid
            this.IdentificationDataGrid.IsEnabled = false;
            this.RelatedEntitiesGridFooter.IsAddButtonEnabled = false;
            this.RelatedEntitiesGridFooter.IsEditButtonEnabled = false;
            this.RelatedEntitiesGridFooter.IsDeleteButtonEnabled = false;
            this.EditIdentificationGroupBox.Focus();
            break;

        case DELETE_OPERATION:
            this.EditIdentificationGroupBox.IsEnabled = false;

            break;

        default:
            this.EditIdentificationGroupBox.IsEnabled = false;

            if (this.IdentificationDataGrid.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                this.RelatedEntitiesGridFooter.IsAddButtonEnabled = true;
                this.RelatedEntitiesGridFooter.IsEditButtonEnabled = false;
                this.RelatedEntitiesGridFooter.IsDeleteButtonEnabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.RelatedEntitiesGridFooter.IsAddButtonEnabled = true;
                this.RelatedEntitiesGridFooter.IsEditButtonEnabled = true;
                this.RelatedEntitiesGridFooter.IsDeleteButtonEnabled = true;
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

I want to know is there is any better approach for effectively handling controls state in code behind?

Comment: delete all that horrible code and use proper DataBinding. a simple `IsEnabled="{Binding Operation, Converter={my:EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=YourEnum}` will suffice.

Comment: It is definitely a good idea to encapsulate this logic in a single method. However, in WPF you may define Visual States for your controls and windows, and then transition them into these states by the [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.aspx) class. Start reading here: [Defining different visual states for a control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee371169(v=Expression.40).aspx).

Comment: @HighCore - the organisation is not using MVVM pattern. We are just using WPF but as a WinForms where all the event handling is done on code behind file.

Comment: @Deepanshu `We are just using WPF but as a WinForms` - ahh! ok!, then the solution is this: **Delete all that horrible code and use proper DataBinding**.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure using winform way of code-behind handling is right way to go. WPF was specifically designed to get rid of tight coupling of view with code-behind. I would suggest to use MVVM pattern (Model-View-ViewModel) intended for WPF which would solve all these issues you mentioned.

Comment: Yes MVVM is the best way to handle such things, but i am bound with the current framework we are using. Also i am learning WPF and want to learn every in and out of it. Can u please suggest any good documentation or handbook for this?

Comment: Till you move to MVVM there is not much you optimization you can do or even if you do it will not be reusable or extensible which is main principle of OOPS. So sooner you refactor the code to use MVVM is better. For starting you can refer this site 
[link](http://www.wpftutorial.net/)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome link...Yes we have lot of redundant code in project.